# how to stop a browser from redirecting next page inorder to get the api from network console on last submit button click

Tags: browser

here I cannot use the debugger as I don't have access to code which is uploaded in production. One thing I can do is to pause chrome browser.

Comment: Can you specify your problem? How is this redirect being added to the page? Do you have acces to JS files? We can't help you with no information

Comment: I don't have the access to js files in production but I do have access to dev js files. The thing is its a Sitecore project and API works fine in dev server but it doesn't work in production. I only need to check response in network console. Anyways to pause the browser.